# One liner to replace the timestamp with current time in a file

Tags: json, shell, perl

I have a file which contains a timestamp:

```
"buildTimestamp": "2021-07-19T17:00:00Z"
```

I want to replace it with the current build time, using a one-line command.

```
date | xargs -I {} perl -pi -e 's/2021-07-19T17:00:00Z/"$0"/g' serviceProperties.json
```

But it's not working as expected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You should really be using a JSON parser to handle JSON data. [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) can do this job.

If your file looks like

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "buildTimestamp": "2021-07-19T17:00:00Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```sh
jq '.foo.bar.buildTimestamp = (now | strftime("%FT%TZ"))' serviceProperties.json
```

outputs this on Feb 24, 2022 at 16:36:15 America/New_York

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "buildTimestamp": "2022-02-24T21:36:15Z"
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you can't advocate for `jq` at least get the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) perl module in the mix:

```sh
perl -MJSON -MPOSIX=strftime -0777 -nE '
    $json = JSON->new();
    $data = $json->decode($_);
    $data->{foo}{bar}{buildTimestamp} = strftime("%FT%TZ", gmtime);
    say $json->pretty->encode($data);
' serviceProperties.json
```

```json
{
   "foo" : {
      "bar" : {
         "buildTimestamp" : "2022-02-25T14:41:04Z"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: we don't have jq in the build system, otherwise it's a good solution

Comment: At the risk of sounding callous: add it. Put the right tools in your toolbox.

Comment: ha, not up to me

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data in serviceProperties.json

```
[
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2021-07-19T17:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2021-07-19T17:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2021-07-19T17:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2021-07-19T17:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

After running `date +%FT%TZ | xargs -I % perl -pi -e 's/2021-07-19T17:00:00Z/%/g' serviceProperties.json`

serviceProperties.json will be

```
[
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2022-02-25T03:30:20Z"
    },
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2022-02-25T03:30:20Z"
    },
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2022-02-25T03:30:20Z"
    },
    {
        "buildTimestamp": "2022-02-25T03:30:20Z"
    }
]
```

As you are replacing with $0 it will take arguments from perl command and hence you will have unexpected results. Instead replacing with a helper using xargs will do the trick.

To learn more about how xargs is working in this case [read here](https://flaviocopes.com/linux-command-xargs/#:%7E:text=The%20%2DI%20option%20is%20another%20widely%20used%20one.%20It%20allows%20you%20to%20get%20the%20output%20into%20a%20placeholder%2C%20and%20then%20you%20can%20do%20various%20things.)

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -pi -e 's/2021-07-19T17:00:00Z/'"$(date)"'/g' serviceProperties.json
```